# FileSystemWatcher can not detect right file name

Tags: c#

`ERP SAP` write data to my windows folder (...\Item). File on folder is `DEV_CM_ARTMAS_20160329-152112-466.xml`

But when FileSystemWatcher raise Onchange. The FileSystemEventArgs.Name is `Item_Temp326024f0-f587-11e5-8a81-00000018263a`

So how can i convert `Item_Temp326024f0-f587-11e5-8a81-00000018263a to string DEV_CM_ARTMAS_20160329-152112-466.xml` in C#

Comment: FileSystemWatcher cannot detect all events with files for some reason. In my experience with it it was constantly loosing events. You should not rely on it. Consider either finding other solution or rechecking LastWriteTime or something like that in all files after first change event.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the first Changed event occurs when start writing on a temporary file. When all bytes are copied the file is renamed to the right entry.

You can, in this case, catch the Renamed event instead of Changed or try to use a filter (e.g. on the file extension)